# Prove that {a} is a neighborhood of a in a certain metric space.

Tags: general-topology

> Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space such that $d(x,y)=1$ when ever $x\not=y$. Let $a\in X$. prove that $\{a\}$ is a neighborhood of $a$ and constitutes a basis for the system of neighborhoods at $a$

I'm *really* confused because my text (Introduction to Topology by Bert Mendelson) defines a neighborhood as

> a subset $N$ of $X$ such that there is a $\delta>0$  such that $$B(a;\delta)\subset N$$

and $B(a;\delta)$ is defined as

> The subset of $X$ consisting of those points $x\in X$ such that $d(a,x)<\delta$.

But there is no $x\in \{a\}$ such that $0<d(a,x)$, so there's no $\delta>0$ such that $B(a;\delta)\subset\{a\}$.

What am I missing?

Comment: Look at your definitions again: there is no requirement that $0<d(a,x)$. In fact $B(a;\delta)\subseteq\{a\}$ whenever $\delta\le 1$.

Comment: Ohhh. So $B(a;.5)\subseteq \{a\}$, for example. And therefore B={a} is a neighborhood of a.

Comment: Yes, that’s exactly right. Remember, $a$ is **always** an element of $B(a;\delta)$ as long as $\delta>0$.

Comment: And then every neighborhood of a contains {a}, so {a} is a basis for the system of neighborhoods at a?

Comment: Exactly. In order for $\mathscr{B}$ to be a local base at $a$, you just need to know that each member of $\mathscr{B}$ is an open nbhd of $a$ and that if $U$ is *any* open nbhd of $a$, there is some $B\in\mathscr{B}$ such that $a\in B\subseteq U$. If $\{a\}$ is the only element of $\mathscr{B}$, then $\mathscr{B}$ has the desired properties.

Comment: So then isn't it true for any metric space with an element x that {x} is a basis for the system of neighborhoods at x? I'm guessing not because that sounds like a really redundant/useless definition.

Comment: No, the argument that $\{\{a\}\}$ is a base at $a$ uses the fact that $d(x,y)=1$ whenever $x\ne y$. More generally, if $a\in X$, and there is some positive real number $r$ such that $d(a,x)\ge r$ for each $x\in X\setminus\{a\}$, then $\{\{a\}\}$ is a local base at $a$. In this case $a$ is said to be an *isolated point* of $X$.

Comment: Oh because δ must be greater than 0. And in this case it works because there's no x that makes 0<d(a,x)<1.

Comment: Now you’ve got it.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks.

Comment: You’re welcome!